# How to change the appBar background color to match the background color of different tabView pages in flutter?

Tags: flutter, tabview

I'm trying to build a simple app structure with an `appBar`, `tabBar` and 3 `tabView` pages. Each of these pages will have a different background color. I would like this background color to cover the full screen (ie, the space taken up by the AppBar, too) . Therefore, I need the color of the AppBar to change as the user switches between tabs.

This is how far I've got:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Color PrimaryColor = Colors.teal[400];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: false,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              indicatorWeight: 5,
              onTap: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                      PrimaryColor = Colors.teal[400];
                      break;
                    case 1:
                      PrimaryColor = Colors.orange[500];
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      PrimaryColor = Colors.pink[500];
                      break;
                    default:
                  }
                });
              },
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: ''),
                Tab(text: ''),
                Tab(text: ''),
              ],
            )),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.teal[400],
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange[500],
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.pink[500],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This *almost* achieves the UI that I want, but the background only changes when the `tabBar` buttons are pressed, not when the swipe gesture is used to change between tabs.

Would be really grateful for some guidance on how to rectify this. Thank you.

[This image shows a mockup of the UI of the 3 tab screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhIXO.png)

[This image shows a mockup of the transition between tabs 1 and 2, where the whole background, including that of the app Bar, changes on swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BZpT.png)

Comment: can you show us a picture of what you trying to achieve?

Comment: @yahyaparvar added as requested, thanks

Comment: I think my solution meets your requirement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want transparency in the AppBar when the color change you can use the `Stack` Widget to place the `TabBar` above the pages:

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: 3,
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      children: [
        TabBarView(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 132.0), //note that without this padding the content of the page will apear behind the TabBar
              color: Colors.teal[400],
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange[500],
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.pink[500],
            ),
          ],
        ),

        Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
            Text(
              'Title',   //A text to represent the title of the image
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            TabBar(
              isScrollable: false,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              indicatorWeight: 5,
              onTap: (index) {},
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'Home'),
                Tab(text: 'Groups'),
                Tab(text: 'Profile'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: @The padding that you've inserted to stop the page content sitting behind the tabBar, would this be responsive between devices despite being a hardcoded size?

Comment: I tested it on cell phones and tablets and the result was the same, hardcode is never the best option but for now I have no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

this is because what changes the color is this onTap function

```
 onTap: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                      PrimaryColor = Colors.teal[400];
                      break;
                    case 1:
                      PrimaryColor = Colors.orange[500];
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      PrimaryColor = Colors.pink[500];
                      break;
                    default:
                  }
                });
              },
```

which is just called on tap gesture. the problem is solved in the code below

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
```

@override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Color primaryColor;
  TabController _tabController;
  TabController _tabControllerA;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: 3,
      initialIndex: 0,
    );

    _tabController.addListener(() {
      _handleTabSelection();
    });
  }

  void _handleTabSelection() {
    _tabController.index = _tabController.index;
    setState(() {
      switch (_tabController.index) {
        case 0:
          primaryColor = Colors.teal[400];
          break;
        case 1:
          primaryColor = Colors.orange[500];
          break;
        case 2:
          primaryColor = Colors.pink[500];
          break;
        default:
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: primaryColor,
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: false,
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            indicatorWeight: 5,
            controller: _tabController,
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(
                () {
                  switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                      primaryColor = Colors.teal[400];
                      break;
                    case 1:
                      primaryColor = Colors.orange[500];
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      primaryColor = Colors.pink[500];
                      break;
                    default:
                  }
                },
              );
            },
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'home'),
              Tab(text: 'another one'),
              Tab(text: 'last one'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            Container(
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            Container(
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this will work

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. This code doesn't seem to produce a different effect to my original code?